# Solving implicit function

Tags: equation-solving, implicit

I'd like to solve for a variable in an expression which is in implicit form. See below.

If the `u1` and `u2` functions below were parametric this would be easy although algebraically messy, so I want to show the solution first in implicit form. Here's the code:

```
z = p*u1[c, H, m] + (1-p)*u2[c, A, m]  + lam*((r - n) + w + x - (c + (pi + r)*m)) + MUA*rho*(A - c) +   MUH* rho *(c - H);

zc = FullSimplify[D[z, c]];

zm = FullSimplify[D[z, m]];
```

Solve implicitly for `m`

```
DSolve[zc == zm, m]
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.  In any case, `DSolve[zc == zm, m]` is bad syntax.  You must specify the dependent variable for which you are solving.

Comment: In `zc == zm` m does only appear as an argument of an unknown function. Therefore, you can not solve for m.

Comment: Indeed. sorry it should have been Solve rather than DSolve since this isn't a differential eqn.